# Chrome went crazy (Looks like Static)

Tags: google-chrome

When I open Chrome it looks like these pictures:

[Chrome image1](http://postimg.org/image/3vnnr7eet/)

[Chrome image2](http://postimg.org/image/toyaayos3/)

I had been using it without any problems, I already uninstalled it an re-downloaded it and keeps doing the same.

I'm running it in a VM with Maverick. Like I said I had been using it for a few weeks now without any problem until today.

It does that not only in the webpages but also in Settings and everything related.

I'd really appreciate any kind of help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Uncheck the "User hardware acceleration when available", restart Chrome and your issue should be fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually installed an older version of Chrome and it started working again, maybe there was something with the latest update, after a couple of days (maybe after updating again) it worked fine!